# Array Comparison Behavior Not Matching Between Formula and VBA User Defined Function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I mocked up my VBA Function by using Formulas first.  The Formulas are calculating as expected, but I am getting a "Compile Error: Type Mismatch" error on the VBA equivalent.

**Formula:**

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX({0,5,10,15,20}>7,0),0)
```

**VBA Function:**

```
Dim myArray(): myArray = [{0,5,10,15,20}]
myVar=WorksheetFunction.Match(1, WorksheetFunction.Index(myArray > 7, 0), 0)
```

The goal is to find the index of the array that first exceeds a provided value, in this case 7.  So the index would be 3.  Unfortunately, the VBA function doesn't seem to be converting `myArray > 7` into a True/False array `{FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE}`.

Is there a way to perform this in VBA without looping through the indexes of the array?

Comment: IMHO, maximum you can do - add a function to loop an array

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to loop through the array? It's really fast.

Comment: VBA doesn't/isn't able to handle arrays in that transform fashion (ie a VBA operation on an array does not implicitly create another array). The more recent 365 worksheet functions haven't found their way to the `WorksheetFunction` object. In this case I don't see how it would be noticeably less efficient to write your own Match, using a While Do loop to iterate over your array until your condition is met. Might even be quicker: imagine if your array had 1000 elements, and your match was at index 2. Even if `Index` worked you would still be eagerly evaluating all 1000 elements unnecessarily.

Comment: If you have Microsoft 365 and you're dealing with integers, you could do `=MATCH(7+1,{0,5,10,15,20},1)` i.e. `myVar = Application.XMatch(7 + 1, myArray, 1)`. If not, here's a sick one: `myVar = Evaluate("=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(--{" & Join(myArray, ",") & "}>7,0),0)")`. But none of these will be faster than a good old loop through the array.

Comment: @Notus_Panda Honestly, I assumed that everything an Excel formula could do that VBA could do, too.  I also assumed that an inline array comparison would be faster and clearer than array looping.  From the comments, it's more a matter of VBA not being able to handle arrays this way and less of an issue with the logic.

Comment: VBA isn't as limited as Excel is in terms of speed so looping through an array is no biggy, I'm not sure why it doesn't have the same implementation but it shouldn't be an issue regardless imo.

Answer (score 0):

### Arrays: Index of First Greater Than

**Usage**

```vb
Dim myArray(): myArray = [{0,5,10,15,20}]
Dim myIndex As Long: myIndex = GetIndexGt(myArray, 7)
```

**The Function**

```vb
Function GetIndexGt( _
    Arr() As Variant, _
    ByVal NumberGT As Double) _
As Long
    Dim Item As Variant, n As Long
    For n = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Item = Arr(n)
        If IsNumeric(Item) Then
            If Item > NumberGT Then Exit For
        End If
    Next n
    If n > UBound(Arr) Then Exit Function
    GetIndexGt = n
End Function
```